# Camera crash provider Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, camera, storage, firemonkey, android-fileprovider

Due to Android 11 and new storage permision, I have set a fileProvider.

From this, every time I launch the camera (Action List -> TTakePhotoFromCameraAction) then my app crash or display :

```
java.lang.illegalArgumentException: failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20220901_161925.jpg
ClassName: EJNIException
```

Do you have an idea ?
I think I missed something in the fileprovider.
I target API 30

Answer (score 0):

Try Project, Options, Entitlement List, and then select 'Secure File Sharing'.

Also, remove the fileProvider permission request from your code but keep the permission request for the Camera, Read Storage and Write Storage.

Also, if you do not have a reason to edit the AndroidManifest.template.xml file in your source directory, just rename it to something else and let Delphi recreate it.

Please note that if you want to test this in the iOS emulator (a feature in Delphi Alexandria 11.2), the Apple iOS emulator does not have a camera and it would not work. Just test it on an iOS device.

But under iOS you do not need permissions, the way you need them for Android, so your Android code would have to be isolated with
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
{$ENDIF}